# The uniqueness of graph closure

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose *G* is a graph on *n* vertices. Then the ***closure*** of *G*, written [*G*], is constructed by adding edges that connect pairs of non-adjacent vertices *u* and *v* for which

$\deg(u) + \deg(v) \geq n.$

One continues recursively, adding new edges until all non-adjacent pairs *u*, *v* satisfy

$\deg(u) + \deg(v) < n.$

Is it unique for a graph?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you are adding edges, you can only increase the degrees. Is the second inequality meant to be $\deg(u)+\deg(v)\ge n$ and the first one $\deg(u)+\deg(v)<n$?

Comment: It is also unclear to me from your description whether in one step of the algorithm you just add *one* edge (for some vertices that satisfy the requirements), or whether you join *all* pairs of vertices fulfilling the conditions on degrees.

Comment: @MartinSleziak We add one edge for each step of the algorithm. Also, if we add an edge between non-adjacend vertices, they became adjacend, so their degrees are nor satisfy the requirements since the vertices became adjacent.

Comment: It should provide (for finite graphs) a unique graph, since at some point you stop adding edges.  What motivates this definition?  Gerhard "Looking For Closure As Well" Paseman, 2019.04.27.

Comment: AFAICT, the final result is going to be the same as iterating construction of creating from the graph $G$ a new graph $G'$, where an edge is added *all* pairs with $\deg_G(u)+\deg_G(v)\ge n$. If you describe the construction in this way, it should be clear that the final result is uniquely determined.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman A graph is hamiltonian iff its closure is hamiltonian.

Comment: See also http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00117

Comment: To extend on Bullet51's comment, this result is called [Bondy–Chvátal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem). Its proof usually includes to show that the closure in your post is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many years ago Staszek Radziszowski and I published a very elementary lemma that covers this case and many similar cases.

Let $(X,\le)$ be a partially ordered set and let $\varPhi$ be a family of functions from $X$ to $X$.  Suppose that, for $x,x'\in X$ and $\phi\in\varPhi$ we have $\phi(x)\le x$ and $x\le x'\implies \phi(x)\le\phi(x')$. Call $x\in X$ *$\varPhi$-stable* if $\phi(x)=x$ for all $\phi\in\varPhi$.  Let $\varPhi^*(x)$ be the closure of $\lbrace x\rbrace$ under $\varPhi$.

**Lemma.** For each $x\in X$, $\varPhi^*(x)$ contains at most one $\varPhi$-stable element.

To apply it to this case, $X$ is the set of all (labelled) graphs on $n$ vertices and $x\le x'$ means that $x$ is a **super**-graph of $x'$. There is a function for each pair of vertices $i,j$ which makes them adjacent if their degree sum is at least $n$ and does nothing otherwise.  There is at least one $\varPhi$-stable graph (add edges until you can't add more) so by the lemma it is unique.

See [Lemma 2 of this paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/r45.pdf).